# Is the average gradient of a line between 2 points given as follows?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Given any continuous function between 2 points $a$ and $b$, I'm assuming that the *average* gradient of the function is simply the gradient of the straight line connect by the points $a$ and $b$ (correct me if I'm wrong about this).

Is there any case where it's possible for the *average* gradient of a continuous function to be negative, if it starts at $a$ and ends at $b$, if $a<b$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Assuming that the function is differentiable (otherwise I don't know what the average gradient could be),

$$
f'_{av} = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f'(x)dx = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a},
$$

which is the slope of the straight line through $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by $a\lt b$. If $a$ has coordinates $(x_a,y_a)$ and $b$ has coordinates $(x_b,y_b)$, then the **average gradient** will be given by:$$\frac{y_b-y_a}{x_b-x_a}$$which can be negative if the signs of the numerator and denominator are different, i.e. if either:$$y_a>y_b\text{ AND }x_b\gt x_a$$or,$$y_b>y_a\text{ AND }x_a\gt x_b$$